# How to compare two directories using diff while ignoring non-existing files?

Tags: linux, diff, compare

I would like to use `diff` to compare two directories for differing files, using the `-q` option for brief output. However, the output is cluttered with a lot of files that only exist in one directory, but not the other. Can I force `diff` (or use another tool) to only show files that differ AND exist in both directories?

The current command I use is

```
diff -q <dir1> <dir2>
```

Any ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It prints a bunch of lines like

```
Only in dir1/blah: blah
```

right? So just throw them away with grep.

```
LC_ALL=C diff ... | grep -v '^Only in'
```

The `LC_ALL=C` is to make sure that the standard "Only in" message will be printed, not any translation.

Comment: No option to do this without grep?

Comment: This also filters valid differences starting with "Only in".

Comment: If you have a directory with many terabytes then his is not an option because under the hood it will diff everything.